# select last row by group with "collapse (last) ..." syntax

Tags: stata

I want to select the last row in each subset of the data determined by one or more categorical variables.

---

*Background.* For each ticket in my data set, I have a `ticketid` and multiple transactions (sale, refund, sale, refund, sale...). I am only interested in keeping series that end in "sale".

My first step was to drop `ticketid`s with evenly matched sales and refunds:

```
duplicates tag ticketid, gen(mult)
by ticketid: egen count_sale = total(transtatus == "Sale")
by ticketid: egen count_ref  = total(transtatus == "Refund")

drop if mult & count_sale == count_ref
```

Now, I want to keep just the final sale when `count_sale = count_ref + 1`

```
sort ticketid time
preserve
  ** some collapse command

  save "temp_terminal_sales.dta"
restore
append using "temp_terminal_sales.dta"
```

I can't figure out how (if at all) to use `collapse` here. I think I may just have to `keep if mult`, tag the last row with `by ticketid: gen last = _n == _N` and `keep if last`...? It seems like collapse should work. Here is the (wrong) syntax that seemed intuitive to me:

```
collapse (last), by(ticketid)
collapse (last) *, by(ticketid)
```

These don't work because (i) a `varlist` is required, and (ii) the `by` variables cannot be in the `varlist`.

---

Example data:

```
ticketid time myvar transtatus
1        1    2     "Sale"
1        2    2     "Refund"
2        1    2     "Sale"
3        1    2     "Sale"
3        2    2     "Refund"
3        3    2     "Sale"
3        4    2     "Refund"
4        1    2     "Sale"
4        2    2     "Refund"
4        3    2     "Sale"
```

Desired result:

```
ticketid time myvar transtatus
2        1    2     "Sale"
4        3    2     "Sale"
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of initial data set and how you want it to look? You can "subtract"  list elements using extended macro functions for lists,  if that works for you; see `help macro lists`. This in reference to your final comment.

Comment: Thanks, Roberto. I'll look into that; subtraction from lists sounds like a useful tool. Now that I have an answer, I'm not up to manufacturing an example; I think/hope future questioners can recognize what I'm after. Actually, just a sec, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest generic way to keep the last of a group is as follows. For a concrete example I assume panel data with identifier `id` and time variable `time`:

```
bysort id (time): keep if _n == _N
```

The generalisation is

```
bysort <variables defining groups> (<variable defining order first ... last>): keep if _n == _N
```

Many Stata commands support the `in` qualifier, but here we need `if` and the syntax hinges crucially on the fact that under the aegis of `by:` observation number `_n` and number of observations `_N` are determined within the groups defined by `by:`. Thus `_n == 1` identifies the first and `_n == _N` identifies the last observation in each group.

`drop if _n < _N` is a dual command here.

You touched on this approach in your question, but the intermediate step of creating an indicator variable is unnecessary.

For `collapse` a work-around is presumably just to use some other variable, or even to create one for the purpose as in `gen anything = 1`. But I would always use `by:` for your purpose.

There is a discursive tutorial on `by:` at http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004 Searching the *Stata Journal* archives using `by` as a keyword will reveal more applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and tutorial! I hadn't thought of `by ... drop`. Quick question: what's wrong with `in _N` here? (You say we need `if` instead.)

Comment: More informatively: `in` refers to absolute observation numbers and is not allowed with `by:`. `in _N` never works directly.

Comment: Oh, right, one of those syntax oddities: the index for `in` is different than the indices used in `by` (despite sharing names). I wish they'd document that on the `by` page instead of separately in the huge syntax doc. Thanks, Nick.

Comment: Sure; we all want documentation to focus on what we need and not the rest. I wrote the paper referred to in my answer because the manual entries seemed too terse for many learners, but I'm sure it's unbearably long-winded for many readers.

Answer (score 1):

@NickCox has already provided the general answer. Now that you have given example data, I post a reproducible example with several syntaxes:

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
ticketid time myvar str10 transtatus
1        1    2     "Sale"
1        2    2     "Refund"
2        1    2     "Sale"
3        1    2     "Sale"
3        2    2     "Refund"
3        3    2     "Sale"
3        4    2     "Refund"
4        1    2     "Sale"
4        2    2     "Refund"
4        3    2     "Sale"
end

list, sepby(ticketid)

*-----

* Method 1

bysort ticketid (time): keep if transtatus[_N] == "Sale" // keep subsets
by ticketid: keep if _n == _N // keep last observation of subsets

list

*-----

* Method 2

// list of all variables except ticketid
unab allvars: _all
local exclvar ticketid
local mycvars: list allvars - exclvar

bysort ticketid (time): keep if transtatus[_N] == "Sale" // keep subsets
collapse (last) `mycvars', by(ticketid) // keep last observation of subsets

list

*-----

*Method 3

bysort ticketid (time): keep if transtatus[_N] == "Sale" & _n == _N

list
```

(Remember to reload the data for each method.)

Consider also tagging and then running the following estimation commands with `if`. For example, `regress ... if ...`

Comment: Thanks, Roberto. That `list, sepby` looks handy and the variety of methods helps me come to grips with the syntax. Method 2 doesn't solve my original laziness problem, of not wanting to write out all of my ~20 non-`by` variables (in my real data set) in the `collapse` command. However, it is still informative and useful. Funny thing: I ended up not keeping the last entry after all. Refunds were routinely miscoded with the correct day but the wrong time (in fact, copying the time from the original purchase), so they could appear after a final sale. Fortunately, it's sorted out now. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I added some code for the "laziness" issue. But I too prefer the methods using `by:` and `keep`.